# ksmserver takes a lot of memory

Tags: kde, memory, nvidia, memory-leaks

For some reason `ksmserver` started to take huge amount of memory (1.6 Gb at the moment). The longer the uptime the more it takes. Seems like a memory leakage for me. Unfortunately, I didn't notice the exact moment when it began to misbehave, probably some update or something. I kinda suspect `nvidia` drivers, is there a way to find out the reason for sure? Maybe check some logs?
Linux Mint 18.1

Comment: Same here, kde-plasma/plasma-workspace-5.8.6 on Gentoo :(